# Is there any continuous function $f:D^n \to S^{n-1}$ whose restriction to the sphere is the identity?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Is there any continuous function $f:D^n \to S^{n-1}$ whose restriction to the sphere is the identity ? If there does not exist such a function then can we deduce Brouwer fixed point thoerem from this ?

Answer (score 0):

If such a function f exists tx+(1-t)f(x) is a retract of the n ball to the n-1 sphere, it is impossible since the n ball is contractible and the n-1 sphere is not contractible